# How to count the number of column with the "TissueA" in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

[image]

How to count the no. of column with the "TissueA" in the dataframe?
and also how to find the values of for eg. TCGA-A6-2676_TissueA,A2M|2

Thanks for your help

Comment: For your other question you can access this cell by typing `df["A2M|2", "TCGA-A6-2676_TissueA"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
length(grep(".*_TissueA", names(dat)))
```

This will return the number of columns that end with _TissueA in your dataframe (dat).

If you want to know the specific indices of those columns (i.e., where they are in your dataframe), just use the 'grep' part:

```
grep(".*_TissueA", names(dat))
```

The return values will give the column indices (this output is just an example, it will be different for your dataframe):

```
[1] 62 63 89 94 95
```

In addition, if you want to actually see a dataframe with the values in those columns (and *only* those columns), try the following:

```
dat[,grepl(".*_TissueA", names(dat))
```